# Try to assign a task to a dynamic sharepoint group and get error: user or group dont have a valid email address

Tags: workflow

I have created a reusable workflow for contentype "ContentTypeX". In this workflow I have an impersonate area. In this area I have a task. In this task I have some subject, comments and dynamic the recipients.

This workflow is started after creating a new item in some list which is using "ContentTypeX". I  have tested it and the task is created. But I see an error:

**Dutch language:**

Waarschuwing cast-conversie: gebruiker of groep beschikt niet over een geldig e-mailadres.

**Translated myself to english:**

Warning cast-conversion: user or group dont have a valid emai address.

Why do I get this error?

This is the error in the workflow information page:
[image]

This is the only user in the sharepoint group:
[image]

This is how I set the recipient of my task. I try getting dynamic the recipient. I look in the list "Beheerders". In this list I have 2 columns:

Departement/Standplaats (Type: Lookup field)

Beheerders (Type: Users or group)

I try to filter on Departement/Standplaats.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by selecting to use the display names of the sharepoint users and groups.